# Regex in Ruby to identify value type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, sinatra

I'm working on a expense tracking project to teach myself regexp, Ruby and Sinatra.  Right now, I have a REST route that receives some text via POST, parses it and writes it to an online spreadsheet.  It's very basic in that you put in a number(mileage), a space and a destination--20 Airport.  It then puts the 20 in one cell and "Airport" in another.  I'm trying to make it a bit "fancier" so it can discern between mileage and expenses.  I'm going to do something like 20m Airport and 30d Groceries to keep it simple.  Here's a snippet from my current code:

```
text  = params["Body"]
match = text.match(/^(\S*)(.*)/)

distance    = match[1].to_f
destination = match[2].strip
```

I think I need to make the new section read something like:

```
text  = params["Body"]
match = text.match(/^([0-9]*)(mMdD)(.*)/)

expamount   = match[1].to_f
exptype     = match[2].strip
expitem     = match[3].strip
```

I'm clearly off in my understand a bit because I'm getting an error `NoMethodError - undefined method [] for nil:NilClass:`

Any help would be most appreciated...thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `text`? It looks like the call to `match` is returning `nil`, which happens if the text doesn't match the regexp.

Comment: Here's my test data for the "new version": `Body=20m%20Airport`

Comment: Just put the `mMdD` in braces `[]`. That is, `/^(\d*)([mMdD])(.*)/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're datatype matcher is a bit too aggressive - `(mMdD)` should be `(m|M|d|D)`, which would indicate any of those modifiers would be accepted. This causes no match to be returned, hence the `NoMethodError` when you attempt to look up an attribute on the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
text  = "Body=20m%20Airport"
match = text.match(/([0-9]+)(m|M|d|D){1}%20([a-zA-Z]+)/)

puts match[1].to_f
puts match[2].strip
puts match[3].strip
```

Or if you convert %20 to a space

```
text  = "Body=20m Airport"
match = text.match(/([0-9]+)(m|M|d|D){1}\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)

puts match[1].to_f
puts match[2].strip
puts match[3].strip
```

I'd recommend [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for working out Ruby regexes, if you don't know it.
Btw, this assumes no numbers or spaces in the name of the expense item. If you need those, you could change the last match group to `[a-zA-Z\d\s]+`